# Android app structure: DLC via in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm building an android app that provides several interactive adventures to the user. These use a lot of media (sound files and images, plus some xml), and therefore a lot of space.

I'm planning on a freemium model where the app is downloaded free with one adventure, and the user can buy more from Google Play.

What I'm wondering is:

1) How do I structure my app so as not to blow 50mb apk?

2) Does internal storage have a size limit?

3) The in-app billing examples I've seen all assume that it's for something trivial that's already in the app. How do I set it up so that an adventure is downloaded when it's purchased?

Answer (score 0):

You can use addons on the Play Store that go up to 2GB (IIRC), so 50mb is only a limit fo the APK. Internal storage is limited by the device's `/data` partition size, but there is no per-app limit (at least not in stock Android). As for 3, you need to have your own server, verify purchases on it and give the app a link to download data once you get a valid order. How exactly you save, load and manage the downloaded data is up to your app.